# TensorFlow Object Detection API: evaluation mAP behaves weirdly?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am training an object detector for my own data using Tensorflow Object Detection API. I am following the (great) tutorial by Dat Tran https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-train-your-own-object-detector-with-tensorflows-object-detector-api-bec72ecfe1d9. I am using the provided ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco-model pre-trained model checkpoint as the starting point for the training. I have only one object class.

I exported the trained model, ran it on the evaluation data and looked at the resulted bounding boxes. The trained model worked nicely; I would say that if there was 20 objects, typically there were 13 objects with spot on predicted bounding boxes ("true positives");  7 where the objects were not detected ("false negatives"); 2 cases where problems occur were two or more objects are close to each other: the bounding boxes get drawn between the objects in some of these cases ("false positives"<-of course, calling these "false positives" etc. is inaccurate, but this is just for me to understand the concept of precision here). There are almost no other "false positives". This seems much better result than what I was hoping to get, and while this kind of visual inspection does not give the actual mAP (which is calculated based on overlap of the predicted and tagged bounding boxes?), I would roughly estimate the mAP as something like 13/(13+2) >80%.

However, when I run the evaluation (`eval.py`) (on two different evaluation sets), I get the following mAP graph (0.7 smoothed):
[mAP during training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOCZI.png)

This would indicate a huge variation in mAP, and level of about 0.3 at the end of the training, which is way worse than what I would assume based on how well the boundary boxes are drawn when I use the exported `output_inference_graph.pb` on the evaluation set.

Here is the total loss graph for the training:
[total loss during training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6O6m.png)

My training data consist of 200 images with about 20 labeled objects each (I labeled them using the labelImg app); the images are extracted from a video and the objects are small and kind of blurry. The original image size is 1200x900, so I reduced it to 600x450 for the training data. Evaluation data (which I used both as the evaluation data set for `eval.py`and to visually check what the predictions look like) is similar, consists of 50 images with 20 object each, but is **still in the original size** (the training data is extracted from the first 30 min of the video and evaluation data from the last 30 min).

Question 1: Why is the mAP so low in evaluation when the model appears to work so well? Is it normal for the mAP graph fluctuate so much? I did not touch the default values for how many images the tensorboard uses to draw the graph (I read this question: [Tensorflow object detection api validation data size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45551196/tensorflow-object-detection-api-validation-data-size) and have some vague idea that there is some default value that can be changed?)

Question 2: Can this be related to different size of the training data and the evaluation data (1200x700 vs 600x450)? If so, should I resize the evaluation data, too? (I did not want to do this as my application uses the original image  size, and I want to evaluate how well the model does on that data).

Question 3: Is it a problem to form the training and evaluation data from images where there are multiple tagged objects per image (i.e. surely the evaluation routine compares all the predicted bounding boxes in one image to all the tagged bounding boxes in one image, and **not** all the predicted boxes in one image to one tagged box which would preduce many "false false positives"?)

(Question 4: it seems to me the model training could have been stopped after around 10000 timesteps were the mAP kind of leveled out, is it now overtrained? it's kind of hard to tell when it fluctuates so much.)

I am a newbie with object detection so I very much appreciate any insight anyone can offer! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Question 1:** This is the tough one... First, I think you don't understand correctly what mAP is, since your rough calculation is false. Here is, briefly, how it is computed:

- For each class of object, using the overlap between the real objects and the detected ones, the detections are tagged as "True positive" or "False positive"; all the real objects with no "True positive" associated to them are labelled "False Negative".
- Then, iterate through all your detections (on all images of the dataset) in decreasing order of confidence. Compute the accuracy (`TP/(TP+FP)`) and recall (`TP/(TP+FN)`), *only counting the detections that you've already seen ( with confidence bigger than the current one) for TP and FP*. This gives you a point (acc, recc), that you can put on a precision-recall graph.
- Once you've added all possible points to your graph, you compute the area under the curve: this is the Average Precision for this category
- if you have multiple categories, the mAP is the standard mean of all APs.

Applying that to your case: in the best case your true positive are the detections with the best confidence. In that case your acc/rec curve will look like a rectangle: you'd have 100% accuracy up to (13/20) recall, and then points with 13/20 recall and <100% accuracy; this gives you `mAP=AP(category 1)=13/20=0.65`. And this is the best case, you can expect less in practice due to false positives which higher confidence.

Other reasons why yours could be lower:

- maybe among the bounding boxes that appear to be good, some are still rejected in the calculations because the overlap between the detection and the real object is not quite big enough. The criterion is that *Intersection over Union (IoU)* of the two bounding boxes (real one and detection) should be over `0.5`. While it seems like a gentle threshold, it's not really; you should probably try and write a script to display the detected bounding boxes with a different color depending on whether they're accepted or not (if not, you'll get both a FP and a FN).
- maybe you're only visualizing the first 10 images of the evaluation. If so, change that, for 2 reasons: 1. maybe you're just very lucky on these images, and they're not representative of what follows, just by luck. 2. Actually, more than luck, if these images are the first from the evaluation set, they come right after the end of the training set in your video, so they are probably quite similar to some images in the training set, so they are easier to predict, so they're not representative of your evaluation set.

**Question 2:** if you have not changed that part in the config file `mobilenet_v1_coco-model`, all your images (both for training and testing) are rescaled to 300x300 pixels at the start of the network, so your preprocessings don't matter.

**Question 3:** no it's not a problem at all, all these algorithms were designed to detect multiple objects in images.

**Question 4:** Given the fluctuations, I'd actually keep training it until you can see improvement or clear overtraining. 10k steps is actually quite small, maybe it's enough because your task is relatively easy, maybe it's not enough and you need to wait ten times that to have significant improvement...

Comment: Thank you for a clear explanation! :) really helped a lot!

Comment: I now understand 4 things: Accuracy, Recall, AP and mAP. You did me a solid favor by writing this small text. Keep in mind that I have networks deployed in production and I coulnd't find a proper explanation for these concepts. Well done sir!